# Pass part of an object to a REST service

Tags: json, rest

Hi everyone I need to pass an object to a REST service via POSTMAN. The object in question has several fields, out of which only some fields have actual values set and need to be passed to the rest service via postman. So it is possible to do so and if so, can anyone please help me with the steps for this?

So the Rest service accepts an object of the class defined as follows:

```
public class SearchCriteria{
 int a;
 String b;
 int[] c;
 String d;
}
```

In postman, I have entered the URL and selected the method type as post. In the body tab, I need to pass something like this:

```
{
"a": 1,
"b": "test"

}
```

So is this possible or do I need to specify empty values for c and d? Also, is the above process correct? I'm very new to postman, so please help!

Comment: Depends on that REST service... No, JSON is not required to be complete, and Postman doesn't care

Comment: Most services have mandatory and optional parameters. Not sure what you are asking here. And why asking first when you could instead just make that experiment yourself quickly?

Comment: The service does not accept individual parameters, it accepts an object of the class SearchCriteria. So I'm not sure, also I'm new to REST, JSON and postman. I am trying to experiment with it myself. So when I invoke the service via postman, nothing happens.. the service does not get invoked. Any idea what could be wrong here? This is an existing code base built by some other developers...